# gnuradio installation error

Tags: software-installation, gnuradio

I am installing `gnu radio` using pybombs but the installation fails with the following error:

```
PyBombs.Packager.source - ERROR - Problem occured while building package apache-thrift:
Installation failed
PyBombs.install - ERROR - Error installing package apache-thrift. Aborting.
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you have `pkg-config` installed? It is a dependency that produces the above error.

Comment: how to know there is a pkg-config is installed

Comment: Let me get more info from the above: Which Ubuntu version are you using? How are you trying to install gnu radio? What steps or tutorial are you following? This will help me know exactly how to help you. Kindly [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/734802/edit) your question and include this info.

Comment: To know whether pkg-config is installed, open up your terminal and type `sud apt-get install pkg-config` it should either install it or tell you that it's already installed.

Comment: it says pkg-config is already the newest version.
and at the last, Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Okay. Kindly edit your question and supply the needed information from my second comment.

Comment: it says the newest version when i try to run sud apt-get install pkg-config

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested by installing gnu-radio from pybombs only, then read requirements for build it from sources, or look at [build-script](http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio) where you can see all needed dependencies for successfull build. Or, just run it, and it will do all job itself.

UPD: to avoid some possible errors, check if you gcc-compiler version are >= 5, but not => 6

UPD2: After reading the comment below, I will post a list of dependencies from the above script and, since you did not provide information about your version of the Ubuntu, I will use pkg-list for 15/16.

```
libqwt6 libfontconfig1-dev libxrender-dev libpulse-dev swig g++
automake autoconf libtool python-dev libfftw3-dev
libcppunit-dev libboost-all-dev libusb-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev fort77
libsdl1.2-dev python-wxgtk2.8 git-core
libqt4-dev python-numpy ccache python-opengl libgsl0-dev
python-cheetah python-mako python-lxml doxygen qt4-default qt4-dev-tools libusb-1.0-0-dev
libqwt5-qt4-dev libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev pyqt4-dev-tools python-qwt5-qt4
cmake git-core wget libxi-dev python-docutils gtk2-engines-pixbuf r-base-dev python-tk
liborc-0.4-0 liborc-0.4-dev libasound2-dev python-gtk2 libzmq libzmq-dev libzmq1 libzmq1-dev python-requests
python-sphinx comedi-dev python-zmq libncurses5 libncurses5-dev python-wxgtk3.0
```

Also, if you have already installed gnuradio via apt-get i'll recommend to remove it to avoid possible errors. If something goes wrong, you can always install them back :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/716636)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, Thanks for the comment, I made corrections.